# Combining Multiple Dataframes Based On Multiple Columns Matching And Summing Other Columns Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, database, join, sum

I currently have multiple pandas dataframes like below:

```
df1
           id1    id2   col_sum_1  col_sum_2
0           13     15       3         4
1           15     234      7         6
2           63     627      1         7

df2
           id1    id2   col_sum_1  col_sum_2
0           13     15       8         3
1           15     234      2         3
2           63     627      8         1

df3
           id1    id2   col_sum_1  col_sum_2
0           13     15       3         5
1           15     234      7         7
2           63     627      4         4
```

I want to create a new dataframe from these where I join when id1 and id2 are matched. Then summing col_sum_1 and col_sum_2 together to get the following outcome

```
df
           id1    id2   col_sum_1  col_sum_2
0           13     15       14         12
1           15     234      16         16
2           63     627      13         12
```

Is there a way to join 3 tables where id1 is equal and id2 is equal and then summing the rows for col_sum_1 and col_sum_2 together to create a new dataframe based of the join and sums in pandas?

Answer (score 0):

`merge()` all three data frames then `sum(axis=1)` (across the row).  Finally cleanup the columns.

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""           id1    id2   col_sum_1  col_sum_2
0           13     15       3         4
1           15     234      7         6
2           63     627      1         7
"""), sep="\s+")
df2 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""           id1    id2   col_sum_1  col_sum_2
0           13     15       8         3
1           15     234      2         3
2           63     627      8         1"""), sep="\s+")
df3 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""           id1    id2   col_sum_1  col_sum_2
0           13     15       3         5
1           15     234      7         7
2           63     627      4         4"""), sep="\s+")

(
    df1.merge(df2, on=["id1","id2"])
    .merge(df3, on=["id1","id2"])
    .assign(col_sum_1=lambda dfa: dfa.loc[:,[c for c in dfa.columns if "col_sum_1" in c]].sum(axis=1),
            col_sum_2=lambda dfa: dfa.loc[:,[c for c in dfa.columns if "col_sum_2" in c]].sum(axis=1),
           )
    .drop(columns=["col_sum_1_x","col_sum_2_x","col_sum_1_y","col_sum_2_y"])
)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you can concatenate the dataframes:

```py
>>> df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3]).groupby(['id1', 'id2']).sum().reset_index()
>>> df
   id1  id2  col_sum_1  col_sum_2
0   13   15         14         12
1   15  234         16         16
2   63  627         13         12
```

**Note:** The above produces the desired dataframe for the 3 "input" dataframes in the question. The next steps are not needed if all the "input" dataframes have only rows with the same pairs of `id1` and `id2` values.

Then, you can find the common `id1` and `id2` pairs in the "input" dataframes:

```py
>>> common_pairs = set(zip(df1.id1, df1.id2)) & set(zip(df2.id1, df2.id2)) & set(zip(df3.id1, df3.id2))
>>> common_pairs
{(63, 627), (13, 15), (15, 234)}
```

Finally, you can create a `MultiIndex` and use it to keep only the rows with the `common_pairs`:

```py
>>> idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df[['id1', 'id2']])
>>> df = df.loc[idx.isin(common_pairs)].reset_index(drop=True)
>>> df
   id1  id2  col_sum_1  col_sum_2
0   13   15         14         12
1   15  234         16         16
2   63  627         13         12
```